# Django Admin ignoring CharField max_length

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a model with several CharField and SlugField instances, like:

```
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, db_index=True, blank=False, null=False)
```

but when I view the field in admin, it renders as:

```
<input name="slug" value="some-arbitrary-value-much-longer-than-10-characters" maxlength="10" type="text" id="id_slug" size="200" />
```

and attempting to edit or save triggerse Django Admin's built-in JS form field validation that notifies me that only 10 characters are allowed.

The only "strange" thing I'm doing in my admin.py is I'm using a formfield_overrides declaration to increase the length of all CharField and SlugFields, since by default they're very short.

So my ModelAdmin looks like:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    formfield_overrides = {
        models.CharField:{
            'widget': TextInput(attrs={'size':'200',})
        },
    }
```

If I comment out the line `'widget': TextInput(attrs={'size':'200',})` the problem goes away. Why is this?

How can I fix this problem while also increasing the display length of *all* Char/SlugFields in my ModelAdmin?

Comment: The SlugField model field uses the SlugField form field in the Django admin. This form field is simply a subclass of CharField with a specialized validator.

AFAIK, Django 1.6 does not implement client side (JS) validation, nor does it state anywhere that length of maximum 10 chars is allowed (i.e: the default length for a models.SlugField is 50 chars).

Please add the exact message you are receiving (copy paste if possible), which Django version you are using and whether you are using a Django admin skin/upgrade (such as admin-tools or grappelli).

Comment: What happens if you don't use `formfield_overrides` at all?